# How to split a pyspark dataframe into 2 dataframe on the basis of groups

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I made a dataframe in pyspark-

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("S1", "S1_P1", "i1"),
    ("S1", "S1_P2", "i2"),
    ("S1", "S1_P3", "i3"),
    ("S2", "S2_P1", "i4"),
    ("S3", "S3_P1", "i5"),
    ("S3", "S3_P2", "i6"),
    ("S4", "S4_P1", "i7")
],["State", "Person", "Item"])
```

and it looks this-

```
+-----+------+----+
|State|Person|Item|
+-----+------+----+
|   S1| S1_P1|  i1|
|   S1| S1_P2|  i2|
|   S1| S1_P3|  i3|
|   S2| S2_P1|  i4|
|   S3| S3_P1|  i5|
|   S3| S3_P2|  i6|
|   S4| S4_P1|  i7|
+-----+------+----+
```

Now I want to group it on "State" put the first two groups into one new dataframe (df1) and all the rest in another new dataframe (df2) such that,

df1 (with first 2 groups) would look like-

```
+-----+------+----+
|State|Person|Item|
+-----+------+----+
|   S1| S1_P1|  i1|
|   S1| S1_P2|  i2|
|   S1| S1_P3|  i3|
|   S2| S2_P1|  i4|
+-----+------+----+
```

and df2 (with all the remaining groups) would look like-

```
+-----+------+----+
|State|Person|Item|
+-----+------+----+
|   S3| S3_P1|  i5|
|   S3| S3_P2|  i6|
|   S4| S4_P1|  i7|
+-----+------+----+
```

How do I achieve this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way : Using joins

- prefer this if you have multiple columns or when `collect` is huge

```
val selectedDf = df.select("State").distinct().orderBy("State").limit(2)

df1 = df.join(selectedDf, ['State'],how='inner')
df2 = df.join(selectedDf, ['State'],how='left_anti')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined way of saying first 2 in spark, unless you explicitly `order` it.

```
first2StateList = df.select("State").distinct().orderBy("State").limit(2).collect() 

//This list will contain [S1,S2] , use it to filter your original df

df1 = df.filter(df.State.isin(first2StateList))
df2 = df.filter(~df.State.isin(first2StateList))
```

Note : Use collect only when the use case list is small

Comment: this helps!
but what if there was one more column, say 'Country' and I had to take first 2 of the groups formed by 'State' and 'Country'?
Can you help me with this too, please?

Comment: @n0obcoder ,  Posted another answer that can handle multiple columns. Just add comma separated columns like `"state","country"`